# javascript error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Keep on getting the Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error"" with: 
(still a work in progress) It is only meant to add an image to the div as a kind of place holder.

```
var board=document.getElementsByClassName("square");
var blank = "<img src = blank.png alt= blank class = blank></img>";
for(var x in board){
  document.board[x].innerHTML(blank)
}
```

This is still a work in progress I do however require the board to test is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Play four-in-a-Row</title>
    <meta charset=ütf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <body onload="boardSetup()">
      <div id="header" >
        <h1 id = "Main">Four-in-a-Row</h1>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <table  border="1" id = "drop">
        <tr>
          <td data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 1"></td>
          <td data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 2"></td>
          <td data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 3"></td>
          <td data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 4"></td>
          <td data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 5"></td>
          <td data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 6"></td>
          <td data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Column 7"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <hr>
      <div id="board" >
        <div class="row">
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure " ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure " ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure " ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure " ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure " ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>
          <div class = "sqaure " ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div  class= "piece">
        <img src= "player_1.png" alt= "Player 1 piece" height = 15% width = 15% id = "player1" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Player one's piece"class ="player1 piece"></img>
        <img src= "player_2.png" alt= "Player 2 piece" height = 15% width = 15% data-toggle="tooltip" title = "Player two's piece" class = "player2 piece"></img>           
      </div>
      <script>
        var map;
        function boardSetup(){
          var board=document.getElementsByClassName("square");
          var blank = "<img src = blank.png alt= blank class = blank></img>";
          for(var x in board){
            document.board[x].innerHTML(blank)
          }

          document.getElementById("board").innerHTML=board;
          var temp2 = document.getElementsByClassName("blank");

          for(var z in temp2){
            temp2[z].className += " piece";
          }
        }

        function gameStart(){}

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();               
        });

        function draggover(ev){

        }

        function drag(ev){

        }
      </script>
      <input type="button" onclick="boardSetup()" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ></input>
    </div>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <hr>
    <a href="../index.html">&lt;- Back to launch page</a>
    <hr>
    <p style= "text-align: right"> done by <br>Justin Michel <br> u14369852</p>
    <hr>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: What line of your code is throwing that error? Also, `<img>` elements don't have a closing tag.

Comment: you seem to have a typo in sqaure
`<div class = "sqaure col-xs-1" ></div>`

Comment: Don't use `for...in...` to iterate over the elements of an array-like collection. [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: `var blank = "<img src = blank.png alt= blank class = blank></img>";` Add quotes to HTML attribute values! -- 
            `document.board[x].innerHTML(blank);` You set this with an equal sign; it's a variable, not a method.

Comment: @Feathercrown HTML attribute values only need quotes around them if the value contains a space.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Huh, TIL. It's still a good idea to get in the habit of doing it, though.

Comment: @Feathercrown Yes, but that is not related to the error and it is incorrect to say that you must use them.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's still something that should be "fixed," though. However, since it isn't actually the problem, it belongs in a comment, not in an answer.

Comment: @Feathercrown It's not broken. It's perfectly valid and therefore it's not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a `for/in` loop to loop over a **[node list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** (the set of DOM elements returned from your `.getElementsByClassName()` call), which is an **[array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects)**. When you do that, you aren't iterating the elements within the collection, you are iterating the properties of the node list object itself.

**You should be using a counting loop to iterate the node list or a `.forEach` loop on the node list that has been converted to an Array.**

You also shouldn't qualify the DOM element you are looping over with `document` as the variable `board[x]` is a direct reference to the element.

Additionally, **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** is a property, not a method. You set it equal to the value you want to use, you don't pass it into it.

Lastly, HTML `<img>` elements do not get closed (`</img>`). They are elements that are not allowed to have "content", like: `<br>`, `<meta>`, `<link>`, `<hr>` and `<base>`.

Here's a simple counting loop that will iterate the elements returned:

```
    var board=document.getElementsByClassName("square");
    var blank = "<img src='blank.png' alt='blank' class ='blank'>";
    for(var x = 0; x < board.length; ++x){
        board[x].innerHTML = blank;
    }
```

And, JavaScript Arrays support a native **[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method that allows the elements to be iterated. A node list isn't an actual array, so it doesn't implement that method natively, but it is an "array like" object and can be converted to one using the **[Array.slice() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**. That would look like this:

```
var board = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
var blank = "<img src='blank.png' alt='blank' class ='blank'>";

// Call the native slice array method (which returns an array)
// and then call forEach on that array:
Array.prototype.slice.call(board).forEach(function(element){
  element.innerHTML = blank;
});
```

Comment: `.forEach()` will only work after converting the `HTMLCollection`/`NodeList` into an actual array.

Comment: My bad on the QSA reference. And yes, you are right about the use of `.forEach`, but I didn't say it could be used directly on the nodelist. I just said that it could be used.